# Babel preset-env older chrome 40

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I am working with a samsung smart TV. And the software on this tv is old I like to use preset-env if possible I need an older version as 40 but I can't get it working.

Can somebody help me to get an older version of Chrome 40 may work because my error is saying that "SyntaxError: Invalid charter: '`'.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals

```
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "chrome": "40"
        },
        "modules": false,
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "debug": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]]
}
```

Comment: if possible please add error details.

Comment: @Rain.To No i just get a black screen and no error. Am developing for a television errors are not available. If i set chrome from 44 to 40 what i need. I just get a black screen and it takes a newer version of Chrome like 76.

Comment: Please try to compile template literals to old good strings with https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-template-literals